# How does the Average function work in relational databases?

Tags: sql, math, rdbms

I'm trying to find geometric average of values from a table with millions of rows.  For those that don't know, to find the geometric average, you mulitply each value times each other then divide by the number of rows.

You probably already see the problem;  The number multiplied number will quickly exceed the maximum allowed system maximum. I found a great solution that uses the natural log.

http://timothychenallen.blogspot.com/2006/03/sql-calculating-geometric-mean-geomean.html

However that got me to wonder wouldn't the same problem apply with the arithmetic mean?  If you have N records, and N is very large the running sum can also exceed the system maximum.

So how do RDMS calculate averages during queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy to check. For example, SQL Server 2008.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(i int);

INSERT INTO @T(i) VALUES
(2147483647),
(2147483647);

SELECT AVG(i) FROM @T;
```

**result**

```
(2 row(s) affected)
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

There is no magic. Column type is `int`, server adds values together using internal variable of the same type `int` and intermediary result exceeds range for `int`.

You can run the similar check for any other DBMS that you use. Different engines may behave differently, but I would expect all of them to stick to the original type of the column. For example, averaging two `int` values `100` and `101` may result in `100` or `101` (still `int`), but never `100.5`.

For SQL Server this behavior is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx). I would expect something similar for all other engines:

> AVG () computes the average of a set of values by dividing the sum of
>   those values by the count of nonnull values. If the sum exceeds the
>   maximum value for the data type of the return value an error will be
>   returned.

So, you have to be careful when calculating simple average as well, not just product.

---

Here is extract from [SQL 92 Standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> 6) Let DT be the data type of the < value expression >.
>
> 9) If SUM or AVG is specified, then:
>
> a) DT shall not be character string, bit string, or datetime.
>
> b) If SUM is specified and DT is exact numeric with scale S, then the
>   data type of the result is exact numeric with implementation-defined
>   precision and scale S.
>
> c) If AVG is specified and DT is exact numeric, then the data type of
>   the result is exact numeric with implementation- defined precision not
>   less than the precision of DT and implementation-defined scale not
>   less than the scale of DT.
>
> d) If DT is approximate numeric, then the data type of the result is
>   approximate numeric with implementation-defined precision not less
>   than the precision of DT.
>
> e) If DT is interval, then the data type of the result is inter- val
>   with the same precision as DT.

So, DBMS can convert `int` to larger type when calculating `AVG`, but it has to be an `exact numeric` type, not floating-point. In any case, depending on the values you can still get arithmetic overflow.

Comment: For your information: your example works just fine in Postgres (and Oracle).

Answer (score 1):

Most databases don't support a `product()` function the way they support an average.

However, you can use do what you want with logs.  The product (simplified) is like:

```
select exp(sum(ln(x)) as product
```

The average would be:

```
select power(exp(sum(ln(x))), 1.0 / count(*)) as geoaverage
```

or

```
select EXP(AVG(LN(x))) as geoaverage
```

The LN() function might be LOG() on some platforms...

These are schematics.  The functions for `exp()` and `ln()` and `power()` vary, depending on the database.  Plus, if you have to take into account zero or negative numbers, the logic is more complicated.

Comment: Doesn't `EXP(AVG(LN(x)))` calculate the geometric mean?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know an exact implementation for arithmetic mean in an RDBMS, nor did you specify one in your original question.  But the RDBMS does not need to sum a million rows in a column in order to obtain the arithmetic mean.  Consider the following summation:

```
sum = (x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + x1000000)
```

Then the mean can be written as

```
mean = sum / N = (x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + x1000000) / N, for N = 1,000,000
```

But this expression can be broken up into pieces like this:

```
mean = [(x1 + x2 + x3) / N ] + [(x4 + x5 + x6) / N] + ...
```

In other words, the RDBMS can simply scan down the million rows in a column and find the mean section by section, without running the risk of an overflow.  And since each number in the column is presumably within range for the type storing it, there is no chance of the mean value itself overflowing.

Comment: It would be very difficult to implement this in practice, so I bet that all engines do simple `SUM`, then divide by `COUNT`. And if `SUM` exceeds the range of values of a certain type - there will be an error. Some engines may use large type for storing intermediary results (64 bit `int`, even if column is 32 bit), so ultimate answer is - it depends / check the docs.

Comment: A primary difficulty with this approach is that there's usually one or more filter conditions and it is hard to determine the correct value of N before you've processed the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Some DBMS — specifically, the Informix DBMS — convert from an INT type to a floating point type to do the calculation:

```
SQL[2148]: create table t(i int);
SQL[2149]: insert into t values(214748347);
SQL[2150]: insert into t values(214748347);
SQL[2151]: insert into t values(214748347);
SQL[2152]: select avg(i) from t;
214748347.0
SQL[2153]: types on;
SQL[2154]: select i from t;
INTEGER
214748347
214748347
214748347
SQL[2155]: select avg(i) from t;
DECIMAL(32)
214748347.0
SQL[2156]:
```

Similarly with other types.  This can still end with an overflow under some circumstances; you then get a runtime error.  However, it is rather seldom that you exceed the precision — it typically takes a very large number of rows for the sum to exceed the limits, even if you're counting the US deficit over the next century in atto-[Zimbabwean dollars circa 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_Zimbabwe).

Comment: `decimal` is not a floating-point type, it is `exact numeric`. But, point taken, some DBMS convert data to larger type. Apparently, SQL standard doesn't forbid it.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: In most Informix databases, DECIMAL(32) means up to 32 digits with an exponent in the the range of ±126, roughly.  That is a floating point type in my book.  In a MODE ANSI database, DECIMAL(32) means a 32-digit integer type, but few people use a MODE ANSI database with Informix.

Comment: Well, I learned from this question and discussion, that there are many different implementations of SQL standard and I should refrain from making such generic statements. Still, if Informix converts `int` to floating-point when calculating `AVG`, it is against the standard (if I understood the standard correctly, of course). See the extract from the standard in my answer. Which only highlights again that there is no one generic answer and such details should be checked with particular implementation.

Comment: I absolutely agree that sweeping statements are dangerous (I learned that a long time ago, the hard way).   I also agree that DBMS implementations are both devious and various — all abuse the standard in some ways, some more so than others.  Almost any question that doesn't stipulate which DBMS can only invite 'it depends' answers, with examples from some DBMS chosen to suit the person answering.